# Building GStreamer with Qt6

Tags: powershell, gstreamer, qt6

I am trying to build GStreamer with the QT6 plugin using cerbero in the windows powershell, I think this is then using MSYS2. I have managed to point the build to QMake however I am now faced with another problem which is it is unable to find the qsb.exe file from Qt. I can see it myself in the bin folder and I have tried adding the path to MSYS, it just seems strange it is detecting qmake and all the other modules but not qsb. I have attached my error log.

```
Called: `C:\\Qt\\6.6.1\\msvc2019_64\\bin\\qmake6.exe -query` -> 0
stdout:
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64
QT_INSTALL_DATA:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:C:/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.6.1
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/bin
QT_INSTALL_BINS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/plugins
QT_INSTALL_QML:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.6.1
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:C:/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.6.1
QT_HOST_PREFIX:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64
QT_HOST_DATA:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64
QT_HOST_BINS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/bin
QT_HOST_LIBEXECS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/bin
QT_HOST_LIBS:C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:win32-msvc
QMAKE_XSPEC:win32-msvc
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:6.6.1
-----------
Run-time dependency qt6 (modules: Core, Gui, Qml, Quick) found: YES 6.6.1 (qmake)
Program qsb-qt6 qsb found: NO

..\ext\qt6\meson.build:63:6: ERROR: Program 'qsb-qt6 qsb' not found or not executable
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says "not found or not executable".  It is probably not executable.

Comment: I managed to fix it by changing 
qsb = find_program('qsb-qt6', 'qsb', required: qt6_option)

to

qsb = find_program('C:/Qt/6.6.1/msvc2019_64/bin/qsb.exe')

in meson.build. 

Thanks

Comment: @DominicSmith You could post an answer with details to help future readers.

Comment: Keep in mind MSYS has pre-built packages for GST